# Jquery sorting object by its key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have the following object:

```
Object {by: "abritishguy", descendants: 38, id: 12617659, kids: Array[8], score: 133…}
Object {by: "mcgwiz", descendants: 4, id: 12641662, kids: Array[1], score: 8…}
Object {by: "dnetesn", descendants: 19, id: 12617263, kids: Array[5], score: 73…}
Object {by: "samber", descendants: 12, id: 12631162, kids: Array[6], score: 127…}
Object {by: "seanseanme", descendants: 0, id: 12632377, score: 16, time: 1475539307…}
Object {by: "wolframio", descendants: 3, id: 12631876, kids: Array[3], score: 25…}
Object {by: "paloaltokid", descendants: 22, id: 12620209, kids: Array[19], score: 11…}
Object {by: "vfulco", descendants: 1, id: 12620860, kids: Array[2], score: 7…}
Object {by: "forgingahead", descendants: 0, id: 12641351, score: 8, time: 1475638119…}
Object {by: "aylmao", descendants: 0, id: 12630489, score: 4, time: 1475522605…}
```

I need to sort the above object by "score"

So far I tried this:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (idata) {
    itemDataArray.push(idata);

});


$(itemDataArray).sort( function ( a, b ) {
    var attr = {}; // your comparison attribute here
    attr.a = parseInt( a.data( 'score' ) || 0 );
    attr.b = parseInt( b.data( 'score' ) || 0 );
    return attr.a < attr.b ? -1 : attr.a > attr.b ? 1 : 0;
});
```

it doesn't work, please help

Comment: Don't wrap `itemDataArray ` in a jQuery object. Use native `sort`.

Comment: you can also use lodash, it is really helpfull in a project https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#orderBy

Comment: jQuery is mostly for DOM operations. Just use the native language unless you actually are building a jQuery object of elements. However, that `.sort` will happen before the `$.getJSON` response arrives.

Comment: ...since you're using `.data()`, it makes me think you've left out some important details. Seems pretty clear that you know how to use `.sort()`, whether on a jQuery object or a native Array.

Comment: ...I don't think that duplicate considers the details in the question, but since the OP isn't being responsive, I guess it just doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) directly.

In this case a possible string value is implicit casted to number, because of the `-` operator.

Ascending:

```
itemDataArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.score - b.score;
});
```

Descending:

```
itemDataArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.score - a.score;
});
```

Comment: it works the sorting part. when I parse using $.each it doesnt work. do you know why?

Comment: @TanvirAlam, so ad hoc not. please ask a new question.

Comment: @TanvirAlam: Don't ask a new question unless you're willing to provide a complete example. This question should have never been answered in the first place. There are too many open questions about the full situation. This simple, obvious answer doesn't come close to covering the issues and possibilities presented in the question.